# In prepareStatement string value is not setting in its placeholder. help me to sort out this?

Tags: prepared-statement

This is my code and see the error help me. in this code i am trying to get username and password from table `student1`. by using `preparedStatement` but i am getting an error .

```
package jdbcMY;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class demo {

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abhi", "root", "root");

            String sql = "select * from student1 where username = ? ";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, "abhi");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {

                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

More details:

- [here is the table i created in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiwB9.png)
- [here is the error that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ROD.png)

Comment: I tested this with h2 and it works fine. Maybe You have an invisible special character in your sql-String? Or the table student1 is not visible to user root? What happens when you remove the where condition and use only `select * from student1`?

Comment: "select * from student1" this  query works fine...!